# Could not resolve type: IMvxPictureChooserTask>

Tags: image, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms and I'm trying to choose a picture from gallery using this code:

```
var task = Mvx.Resolve <IMvxPictureChooserTask>();
task.ChoosePictureFromLibrary(400, 95, OnPicture, () => { });
```

But I get this error:

```
Could not resolve type:global::Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.Resolve<global::Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.IMvxPictureChooserTask>
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT : Well, in the end I had to change my project's architecture and get the views out of PCL. and that fixed almost everything, although creating iOS view is though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you have added it to your project, but usually when adding through NuGet, it would fix this for you. However, if you manage your own references by adding from your own compiled source or from the binaries you would do this:

In your:

- Core project

  - add Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser
- Touch project

  - add Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.Touch
  - add Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser
- Droid project

  - add Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.Droid
  - add Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser
- WindowsPhone project

  - add Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.WindowsPhone
  - add Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser

etc... You get the pattern now, I hope.

However, this is not enough, just to add the references. You also need to tell MvvmCross that you want to use this plugin. So you have a couple of choices.

1. Add a Bootstrap folder with bootstrap files containing:

   ```
   public class DownloadCachePluginBootstrap
       : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.PluginLoader>
   {
   }
   ```
2. Override `LoadPlugins` in your Setup.cs file for each platform:

   ```
   public override void LoadPlugins(IMvxPluginManager pluginManager)
   {
       pluginManager.EnsurePluginLoaded<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.PluginLoader>();
       base.LoadPlugins(pluginManager);
   }
   ```

Comment: well, I've added them through NuGet, and still no luck.

Comment: do you have an mvvmcross application - are you following @cheesebaron's mvvmcross+forms blog sample?

Comment: @Stuart not exactly, I'm not using setup.cs in this project and all the views are in the Core.I think the trick is using PluginLoader,but still couldn't figure out how to do it without Setup.cs.

Comment: If you are not using any Setup then MvvmCross is not initialized and that is why nothing works...

Comment: You can also take a look at the crosslight examples - a couple of them show plugin use without a full setup

Comment: @Cheesebaron well, everything(bindings,insert and modify methods,etc) except this particular function works OK,that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @Stuart I was wondering if
**Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded ();**
would work?
although it throws this error :
Error 2 The type 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.Plugins.IMvxPluginLoader' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Cirrious.MvvmCross, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/CrossLight you need to set up the IoC, that is what is normally done in the Setup.cs file. If you don't do that. Mvx.Resolve will not be able to find the plugin, as it depends on IoC!

Comment: @Cheesebaron,@Stuart Now I see! I have a TinyIOC module in this project(I'm super new with Xamarin Forms and MvvmCross).
Although I couldn't use override or bootstrap, I will take a look at CrossLight.Thanks.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I tried to register it to ioc container with this 
TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register<IMvxPictureChooserTask,MvxPictureChooserTask>();
but I get this error now,'Cirrious.CrossCore.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidTask' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Cirrious.CrossCore.Droid,
I also tried finding the right place to override load plugin, which was a failure too.